Windows 11 missing mouse cursor
The mouse cursor has disappeared on my Asus Vivobook laptop.
I have tried:

Enabling disabling the track pad using fn f6 keyboard combo
Ive checked in windows settings that the touch pad is enabled. It is.
I've followed this tutorial to no avail
https://mcmw.abilitynet.org.uk/how-to-find-your-mouse-pointer-in-windows-11
Ive tried a reboot/restart
I've tried the ctrl-alt-delete hack that doesn't work either

Can anybody recommend other approaches. I'd like to avoid reinstalling the OS

Ok, so I plugged in a mouse.
The mouse pointer appeared.
Both the track pad and the mouse then worked as expected.
What a time to be alive.

One of my customers called a few days ago with the exact same bug, except they already used a mouse. The mouse light at the bottom was working normally, but no pointer. Unplugging the cable and plugging it back in did not fix it. Plugging in a 2nd mouse fixed it for them too. Sounds like a Windows 11 bug.
